# RLS - Custom "No access" message (Power BI)

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop, row-level-security

Upon setting a RLS filter, users get a blank space if the info contained by the visual (drilled-down table) is not meant for them to see; however, I would like it to display a "No access" message.

I've tried setting a DAX formula upon creating the RLS role in the form of:

`IF([Manager] = "John", [Sales], "No access")`

But to no avail, visuals just generate an error when activating the role.

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to do this within the RLS formula itself.
Instead, you could create a Measure similar to:

```
RLS No Access = COUNTROWS ( ALL('Your RLS Table') ) = 0
```

Then for example, for the Heading of your visual, you can set it to a Measure similar to:

```
Heading My Visual = IF([RLS No Access], "No access", "My visual heading")
```

Comment: Thanks, but that wouldn't fix the problem, since I want the visible rows meant for the user AND the hidden data rows with a "no access" message displayed on the same table object.

Comment: This is simply not possible. You wouldn't even be able to the get the count of hidden RLS rows and for good reason. To the end user, the RLS rows don't exist.

Comment: That was what I was afraid of. Thanks for confirmation

Comment: There is one idea that may work depending on the complexity of your RLS needs. You could for example add the "No access" rows to the same RLS table, then hide/show, kinda of like a reverse RLS, if you know what I mean. "If user has access, show good rows and hide bad rows" and vice versa.